# Additive character : For any field or for a finite field?

Tags: characters

We can define an additive character for any field, can't we? The reason why i'm asking this question is that when i google "additive character", all definitions i have seen are for a finite field. If we can define an additive character, could you give a link to the definition of an additive character for any field?

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search might have found a text about the [Finite Fields Waring Problem](http://web.mit.edu/~holden1/www/coursework/math/18784/Finite%20field%20Waring.pdf) which - in spite of its title - on page 3 gives the very general

> **Definition 2.1.** Let $G$ be an abelian group. A *character* of $G$ is a homomorphism from $G$ to $\mathbb C^\times$. A character is trivial if it is identically $1$. We denote the trivial character by $\chi_0$ or $\psi_0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Hagen von Eitzen.Then you say that the definitions of  a character of an abelian group and an additive character of a field are same, don't you? So we can define an additive character for any field, can't we?